# Associating REST endpoints to TCP ports in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

When implementing REST services using Spring MVC, would it be possible to associate certain paths to specific listener ports?

I.e.

```
listen for POST .../my/resource         on port 3000 
listen for GET  .../my/resource/{id}    on port 3001
```

The app (or should I say 2 app's?) would be deployed using Spring Boot.

Thank you very much,
J.

Comment: Any why do you need to do that? I think port is not tied to Spring MVC, but rather to the servlet container. 

Even if you want to do that, why do you want to differentiate the path if the ports are gonna be different?

Comment: The AWS ELB (loadbalancer) is linked to a particular process/port.  The idea is to serve a number of service-endpoints publicly, through the loadbalacer.  While at the same, keep a set of other resources internal.  [Curious if this remark will drive the discussion in a different direction :-) ]

Comment: If that's the case, your application shouldn't care about which port it is listening to, isn't it? All you need to care from application perspective is to handle all different type of request.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your point.  Anyway, I agree that it feels unnatural to link these concepts (ports vs service paths).

Comment: My point is that your application shouldn't care which port it is listening to. All it needs to care is to handle both `.../my/resourceA/{id_xyz}` and `.../my/resourceB/{id_klm}`.

Comment: OK, but if I want AWS ELB to expose just a subset of these services, the only differentiator I can configure is a port attribute.  Until I have an alternative solution to that, my question holds I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practices we follow while building REST APIs is, never mix multiple resource in one application, what this essentially means is Resource 1 -> App 1, Resource 2 -> App 2 and so on.
What leverage do you get from this ? It is easy to scale one API over other as per traffic, also less code is more managed. Plus versioning goes very simple for a resource.

If you follow this then you can ship this to your runtime env and get flexibility with PORT and all those network related configurations.